# using mysql select query in python curosr

Tags: python, mysql, sql, scripting

I have a select query like this :

`SELECT * FROM simple_tbl WHERE a_name != " " AND d_name != " " AND s_time != "0000-00-00 00:00:00" AND e_time != "0000-00-00 00:00:00"`

I have to use this in a python script, I used the select inside the cursor.execute("query"), but its failing everytime.

Can anyone help me using it  ?

I have used below 2 ways:

1st:
`cursor.execute ("SELECT * FROM maintenance_simple_tbl WHERE acc_name != " " AND device_name != " " AND start_time != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND end_time != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'")`

Error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sync.py", line 42, in <module>
    cursor.execute ("SELECT * FROM simple_tbl WHERE a_name != " " AND d_name != " " AND s_time != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND e_time != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND d_name !=
ND s_time != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND e_time != '000' at line 1")`

2nd: 
`cursor.execute ("SELECT * FROM simple_tbl WHERE a_name != " " AND d_name != " " AND start_time !='%s' AND e_time !='%s'" % (0000-00-00 00:00:00,  0000-00-00 00:00:00))`

Error:

`File "sync.py", line 43
    cursor.execute ("SELECT * FROM simple_tbl WHERE a_name != " " AND d_name != " " AND s_time !='%s' AND e_time !='%s'" % (0000-00-00 00:00:00,  0000-00-00 00:00:00))
                                                                                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you use this query ? Show us some code so we can help you to spot the problem...

Comment: Can you include the error(`traceback`) your getting and also include your python code in your question.

Comment: Did you try this query on the database without te script? Are you 100% sure the query is correct?

Comment: @VincentBeltman, the query is working fine in manula mysql query.

Comment: What do you mean by failing? Don't you get any result? An error?

Comment: Used queries and error updated.

Comment: Your syntax errors are most likely because you are using double-quotes inside your SQL query. Change them to single quotes (`a_name != ' '`) and it should work. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can proceed to query MySQL in Python:

```
import MySQLdb as sql

dbParams = {
    'host': # your database host,
    'port': # your database port,
    'user': # your database user,
    'passwd': # your database password,
    'db': # your database name
}
query = 'SELECT * FROM simple_tbl WHERE a_name != " " AND d_name != " " AND s_time != "0000-00-00 00:00:00" AND e_time != "0000-00-00 00:00:00"'

database = sql.connect(**dbParams) # initiate a connection to your database
cursor = database.cursor() # create a new cursor that you will use to query your database
cursor.execute(query) # this will execute your query
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Instead of `fetchall()` function you could just use `fetchone()` if you want to retrieve the first returned row.

Comment: thanks. I was able to connect and fetch the data. My main issue is to giving quotes properly inside the script.

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answer will work for executing a query and fetching the results, I think that the `DictCursor` object is more in line with what you would want when dealing with MySQL tables. You can use it as follows:

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

def get_db_cursor():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host",
                         user="user",
                         passwd="passwd",
                         db="db_name", 
                         cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur = db.cursor()
    return cur
```

Now, you can use this function as follows to get a cursor:

```
cursor = get_db_cursor()
sql = "SELECT * simple_tbl WHERE a_name != ' ' AND d_name != ' ' AND s_time != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND e_time != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' " # Note that I replaced the double quotes with single quotes 
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

This returns a collection of dictionaries - one for each row in the resulting table. You can iterate over this collection as follows:

```
for row in data:
    if len(row['a_name']) > 5:
        # do something
```